# Retrieving data to a jsp with a MySQL/Tomcat 8 connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat8

I was hoping I could get some help with a problem I was having after searching through similar problems here and not finding a solution to my particular issue.

I have been trying to setup a JDBC connection pool using MySQL and Tomcat 8.  Having setup the JavaEE 7 project in Eclipse Mars, I downloaded the connector and placed it in the CATALINA_HOME/lib folder as directed.  I then added the `<Resource>` tag to CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml and added the corresponding reference to the webapp's web.xml in Eclipse.  I then attempted to use the following JSP to display data from my database:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>TestDataSource</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/shop" >
      SELECT * FROM category, product
      WHERE category.id = product.category_category_id
    </sql:query>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
          <th><c:out value="${columnName}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
      </tr>
      <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
        <tr>
          <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
            <td><c:out value="${column}" /></td>
          </c:forEach>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the first run, the error I received was "Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'for connect URL "null"'".  I corrected this by moving the Resource tag into the webapp's META-INF/context.xml file. The jsp will now display without error except that there is no data.  It just has a small table with $columnName and $column showing.  Going over the jsp I could not identify any errors in the code.  Debugging the app leads me to believe that it is still not able to connect to the database for some reason because it seems to not be getting the url from the data source despite no error being found in the logs when the page is called.

Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/shop" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
      username="root" password="xxx"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop" />

</Context>
```

This is the reference in my WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Connects to database for Toy Shop application</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/shop</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

The following jars are included inside the webapp's lib folder and included in the build path:

> javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar, 
>   javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.2-b02.jar,
>   taglibs.standard-impl-1.2.5.jar

And the pom for the rest of the dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>toyShop</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>toyShop</name>
  <!-- <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.31-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.37</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>toyShop</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I think I've overlooked something basic but I'm not sure.  Any help at this point is appreciated.

Comment: (side note: Oh god there is a "<sql:xxx")

Comment: Slightly unclear. Do you mean that `${columnName}` and `${column}` appear literally in the output?